# How long are the "inburgering" exam results valid for?

Tags: netherlands, residency

Based on the law, after living in the Netherlands for 5 years and passing the integration (inburgering) exam, immigrants can apply for being an official Netherland's citizen. Now the question is: If I take the exam in 2021, can I use the result three years later, or do they expire?

Comment: Will you have lived in the Netherlands for those three years?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems unlikely it would expire. On the presumption that the answer to @Traveller 's question is 'yes', there is no reason to assume that your integration into life in the Netherlands would have *decreased* in that time.

Comment: @Traveller yes I will live for those years in the Netherlands

Comment: Did you find out how long is it valid? DUO refers me to IND... IND to DUO.. In my opinion if I pass it with A2 it should still be a 'pass' no matter than it will be B2 in the future, cause it's already a pass. But I m not sure if it will be valid still..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you pass all the integration tests (inburgeringsexamens) you will be eligible to get an integration diploma (inburgeringsdiploma). **The diploma does not expire** and can be used to apply for permanent residency as well as citizenship.

More information can be found on the [official website of DUO](https://www.inburgeren.nl/index.jsp).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and called the ind.
Apparently it wouldn’t be useful anymore because you will get a certificate saying that your dutch is A2 level.
However after 31/12/2021 they require a diploma with Dutch level B1 , so it will not fulfill the requirement .
I know that wasn’t the answer you were hoping for but this is at least was the answer of the ind when I called them.

Comment: Just an FYI, An A2 diploma will still work at the IND in 2022 per their website: https://ind.nl/en/Pages/Integration-in-the-netherlands.aspx#Civic-integration-for-naturalisation

It says:
The Dutch government is planning to increase the language requirement for the application of a permit 'humanitarian non-temporary' and 'permanent stay', as well as applications for naturalisation, from level A2 to level B1. However, the change in language requirement to level B1 will probably not occur in 2022. Therefore, until further notice, the language requirement will remain level A2 in 2022.

Comment: As per September 2023, A2 level is still valid: https://ind.nl/en/living-in-the-netherlands-with-a-residence-permit/civic-integration-for-more-secure-residence-permit-and-naturalisation#language-level-remains-a2-in-2023